# cmake copying fortran modules failure on linux

Tags: linux, cmake, fortran

I have a fortran code build that uses cmake to build. This is currently working on Mac OS X, but when I try to build it on Linux, it fails. Cmake generates the makefile successfully but when I try to run the makefile it fails when trying to copy the modules.

The top level cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

# Start Project and note the language used.
project (v3fit_suite Fortran)

# Set a directories to build all binary files.
set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
set (LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/lib)

# Fortran specific settings. The first setting tells the compiler to use the C preprocessor. The second places a common directory to place all of the module files.
set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -cpp")
set (CMAKE_Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/modules)

# List all the subdirectories these are in library dependancy order.
add_subdirectory (LIBSTELL)
add_subdirectory (VMEC2000)
add_subdirectory (V3FITA)
add_subdirectory (MAKEGRID)
add_subdirectory (V3POST)
add_subdirectory (V3RFUN)
```

All the modules should be copied to to build/modules. When I run the Makefile with VERBOSE=1 on Linux I get:

```
/usr/bin/cmake -H/home/user/reconstruction -B/home/user/reconstruction --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/user/reconstruction/CMakeFiles /home/user/reconstruction/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make -f LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/build.make LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
cd /home/user/reconstruction && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/user/reconstruction /home/user/reconstruction/LIBSTELL /home/user/reconstruction /home/user/reconstruction/LIBSTELL /home/user/reconstruction/LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make -f LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/build.make LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/requires
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make -f LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/build.make LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f.o.provides.build
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/user/reconstruction/CMakeFiles 
[  0%] Building Fortran object LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f.o
cd /home/user/reconstruction/LIBSTELL && /usr/bin/f95  -o CMakeFiles/stell.dir/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f.o  -cpp  -J../build/modules   -c /home/user/reconstruction/LIBSTELL/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_copy_f90_mod build/modules/stel_kinds LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/stel_kinds.mod.stamp GNU
Error copying Fortran module "build/modules/stel_kinds".  Tried "build/modules/STEL_KINDS.mod" and "build/modules/stel_kinds.mod".
make[3]: *** [LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f.o.provides.build] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make[2]: *** [LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/Sources/Modules/stel_kinds.f.o.provides] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make[1]: *** [LIBSTELL/CMakeFiles/stell.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/reconstruction'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm having the same problem when using the gfortran as my compiler instead of f95. Why is this working on Mac OS X but failing on Linux? On Mac OS X I have version 2.8.8 of cmake installed and on Linux version 2.8.

Comment: The error indicates that the script cannot find the file for some reason.  Is the file `build/modules/stel_kinds.mod` present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there was a seemingly unrelated error that was causing the problem. I had some statements to add an include path that was being empty.

```
find_library (NETCDF_F netcdff PATHS ${NETCDF_LIB_PATH})
find_file (NETCDF_I netcdf.inc ${NETCDF_INC_PATH})
if (NETCDF_C AND NETCDF_F AND NETCDF_I)
    message (STATUS "Using netcdf")
    set (CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} -D NETCDF -I ${NETCDF_INC_PATH}")
endif ()
```

The if statement was always coming up true even when 'NETCDF_INC_PATH' was empty. This was causing an extra -I in the compiler command line that was screwing everything up.